# How do 3rd party app stores know when a new app is added to Google Play?

Tags: web-scraping, google-play

So every time a new app appears on Google Play, the apk of this app is uploaded to some 3rd party websites on that same day (you can find a lot of such sites by searching for `XYZ game apk download`. Do these websites just scrape Google Play? But even if they scrape Google Play how can they find the new app so quickly if even the search results don’t return the app yet?

Answer (score 0):

They probably scrape Google Play using [Python Scraper](https://pypi.org/project/google-play-scraper/) and possibly the frequency of scraping is much higher and prioritized on the basis of the number of downloads and the number of active users of a particular app.

Comment: hello, I just checked Python Scraper and it seems that it can only scrape Google Play if you know the package id of the app. But I don't think that trying all the possible combinations of the package id can be done because of the limit Google imposes on its servers (you will be blocked if you send too many requests).

Comment: @Nfff3, Yes you are right. 
One idea which might work is scraping the New Release(https://play.google.com/store/apps/new) URL because it contains a list of all the new apps.